# According to the Playtest Rules, can a Paladin own a Familiar?

Tags: dnd-5e

I'm here discussing with a friend if the Paladin can have a Familiar or not.

The Familiar Feat says that as long as you have a spell of the Wizard list on your Spell List, you can own a familiar, however my friends says Paladin can't and shouldn't benefit from Familiars.

So, can a Paladin own a Familiar even if it's not a "full spellcaster" like the Cleric or Wizard?

Comment: it might help to specify which version of the playtest you're referring to? I've got the October 2013 release and it doesn't have a familiar feat.

Comment: The packet dated June 7, 2013 ("060713") has the **Find Familiar** feat. Is that what you mean? It doesn't mention Wizard spell lists, so I'm not sure it is.

Comment: Voting to close as "unclear" until it's clarified which rules-as-written are being asking about.

Answer (score 7):

No, paladins take spells from the paladin spell list not from the wizard spell list.  If a paladin wants a familiar it will have to take a level of wizard, or find another way to get a spell from the wizard spell list, such as the arcane initiate feat, or being an elf with a cantrip.

Even though there might be a spell on both lists, that doesn't count as a wizard spell. You can see this language clearly with clerical domain spells.

Comment: Couldn't the Paladin take the _Arcane Initiate_ feat to get the _Find Familiar_ spell?

Comment: @gamerjosh They could, but I'm understanding the question being mainly about the status of paladin.  I'll clarify.

Comment: Or perhaps a high elf paladin with their free wizard cantrip?

Comment: @Aviose Mentioned already, last sentence of the first paragraph in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I feel we need emphasis on methods that don't require multiclassing to keep perceived spirit of request. Race choice seemed the least invasive, with a feat being second, and far more expensive, in my opinion. I admittedly glanced at GMNoob's answer very quickly and mist that last condition.

Comment: @Aviose The spirit of the request is explaining whether the paladin's normal spell access qualifies for the feat. The rest is just bonus: nice to have, but not the point.